# ValueError when trying to run bi-Directional MultiLSTM neural network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_rnn.py", line 92, in <module>
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/iit/sourab/conv_extractive/codes/cnn-text-classification-tf/rnn_code/text_rnn.py", line 65, in __init__
    initial_state_bw=self.rnn_tuple_state_bw)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 375, in bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
    time_major=time_major, scope=fw_scope)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 574, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 737, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2770, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2599, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2549, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 722, in _time_step
    (output, new_state) = call_cell()
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 708, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 916, in call
    cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 752, in __call__
    output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 383, in call
    concat = _linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1017, in _linear
    initializer=kernel_initializer)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1065, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 962, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 360, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1405, in wrapped_custom_getter
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 183, in _rnn_get_variable
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 183, in _rnn_get_variable
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 352, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/home/iit/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 669, in _get_single_variable
    found_var.get_shape()))

**ValueError: Trying to share variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (1024, 2048) and found shape (640, 2048).**
```

Below I pass parameters to the constructor of the TextRNN class.

```
rnn = TextRNN(
    sequence_size=x.shape[1],
    truncated_backprop_length=FLAGS.truncated_backprop_length,
    state_size=FLAGS.state_size,
    num_classes=y.shape[1],
    vocab_size=len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_),
    embedding_size=FLAGS.embedding_dim,
    num_layers=FLAGS.num_layers,
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
```

Here, is the TextRNN class:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

class TextRNN(object):
"""
An RNN for text classification
Uses an embedding layer followed by multilayered Bi-Directional LSTMs followed by a softmax layer
"""

def __init__(
    self, sequence_size, truncated_backprop_length, state_size, num_classes, vocab_size, embedding_size, num_layers, batch_size):

    #placeholders for input, output and dropout probability
    self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, sequence_size], name="input_x")
    self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size,truncated_backprop_length, num_classes], name="input_y")
    self.dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")

    self.fw_init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_layers, 2, batch_size, state_size])
    self.bw_init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_layers, 2, batch_size, state_size])

    # Embedding layer
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
        self.W = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
            name="W")
        embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
        #embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars, -1)
        self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.reduce_mean(embedded_chars, axis=2)



    state_per_layer_list_fw = tf.unstack(self.fw_init_state, axis=0)
    self.rnn_tuple_state_fw = tuple(
        [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list_fw[idx][0,:,:], state_per_layer_list_fw[idx][1,:,:])
        for idx in range(num_layers)]
        )

    state_per_layer_list_bw = tf.unstack(self.bw_init_state, axis=0)
    self.rnn_tuple_state_bw = tuple(
    [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list_bw[idx][0,:,:], state_per_layer_list_bw[idx][1,:,:])
        for idx in range(num_layers)]
        )

    W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(2*state_size, num_classes), dtype=tf.float32)
    b2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1,num_classes), dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.name_scope('BiMultiLSTM'):
        with tf.name_scope('forward_cell'):
            cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell( num_units=state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
            cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell_fw, output_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob)
            cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell_fw] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
        with tf.name_scope('Backward_cell'):
            cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell( num_units=state_size, state_is_tuple=True)
            cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell_bw, output_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob)
            cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell_bw] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

        self.output_hidden_states, self.current_states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
        cell_fw=cell_fw,
        cell_bw=cell_bw,
        inputs=self.embedded_chars_expanded,
        initial_state_fw=self.rnn_tuple_state_fw,
        initial_state_bw=self.rnn_tuple_state_bw)

    self.outputs_concat = tf.concat(self.output_hidden_states, 2)
    self.output_series = tf.reshape(self.outputs_concat, [-1, 2*state_size])
    self._current_state_fw = self.current_states[0]
    self._current_state_bw = self.current_states[1]
    #output
    with tf.name_scope("output"):
        self.logits = tf.matmul(self.output_series, W2) + b2 #Broadcasted addition
        self.labels = tf.reshape(self.input_y, [-1, num_classes])

    self.logits_series = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(self.logits, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_classes]), axis=1)
    self.predictions_series = [tf.nn.softmax(logit) for logit in self.logits_series]
    self.labels_series = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(self.labels, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length, num_classes]), axis=1)

    #loss
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        self.losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.logits, labels=self.labels)
        self.total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.losses)

    #accuracy
    self.correct_predictions = []
    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        for predictions, labels in zip(self.predictions_series, self.labels_series):
            self.correct_predictions.append(tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, axis=1), tf.argmax(labels, axis=1)))
        self.sum_predictions = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(self.correct_predictions, tf.float32))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(self.correct_predictions, tf.float32))
```

These are the parameters that I passed:

```
Parameters:
ALLOW_SOFT_PLACEMENT=True
BATCH_SIZE=50
CHECKPOINT_EVERY=100
DATA_FILE=./../data/cnn_train.txt
DEV_FILE=./../data/cnn_test.txt
DROPOUT_KEEP_PROB=1.0
EMBEDDING_DIM=128
EVALUATE_EVERY=100
LOG_DEVICE_PLACEMENT=False
NUM_CHECKPOINTS=5
NUM_CLASSES=2
NUM_EPOCHS=200
NUM_LAYERS=3
STATE_SIZE=512
TRUNCATED_BACKPROP_LENGTH=10
```

I searched the net but failed to solve the error. The program works if I give **state_size** same as **embedding_size** and gives the above error for all other cases where **state_size** is not equal to **embedding_size**.

Comment: It looks like the backward RNN is trying to reuse the weights from the forward one. Is that intentional?

Comment: I'm running into a very similar error.  I've been through the above code and can't find where the backward RNN is reusing the forward weights.  Can you clarify which area of the code is responsible for this? I suspect it may help me figure out my similar error.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos , I am new to tensorflow and neural nets. Is it necessary for backward RNN to use weights from the forward ones? If not, what has to be done to solve the error? If  backward RNN should use weights from the forward ones, then in this case too how do I solve the error?

Comment: It is not necessary. Use a different variable_scope when building your backward rnn and you should be fine.